# How to avoid global variables in node/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I'm having a hard time deciding what the best pattern would be for avoiding global variables in node.

I have a file server.js which initializes a few Const variables (which give them block scope)

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

server.js is at the root directory level, and i have some routers defined inside a folder for it to import.
Here's my issue.

In my first created router file (so, /Routes/myRouter.js), first thing I wrote was:

```
const express = require("express");const app = express();
const router = express.Router()
```

Now, I get a big fat warning on  my  IDE that tells me "HEY! You  can't declare an "express" variable!! Its already been declared in server.js.
Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'express'.

So the express const variable in my server.js is therefore global and clashing with this declaration in my myRouter.js file.

An easy solution would be to never ever use const so as to avoid global variable, and instead use var for everything, so variables keep to themselves in the files they're created in, but that seems....... like seriously bad practice and misguided.

What do I do? What do professional node devs do? There seems to be an easy fix of adding  the following to the top of every. single. file:

```
export {}
```

but again, that just seems like a lazy, random hack, and I want to follow good practices, not tape together haphazard fixes that eventually break down the road.

Comment: Each module has its own scope, so using the same variable name at the top level of different modules *shouldn't* be an issue, I'd think? It may be that your IDE isn't configured to understand the environment properly

Comment: @CertainPerformance is right on scoped variables. It's probably your IDE giving you error. For me, I have a variables.js file contains my .env var's and const's inside, then i have a config file to create express and other needed stuff and obv it's exporting those and inside server.js i'm just requiring what need and inside routes and everywhere i just import it from the config.js :)

Comment: const doesn't make things any more global than var does. If anything, block scoping (that const uses) is more restrictive than lexical scoping (that var uses). Are you doubly sure you're aren't declaring express twice in the same file? (you don't have two `const/let/var express`)

Comment: If you are using VS code try to remove all js related plugin because i always use `const` and same variable name in router and server file. There should be an issue with your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I guess professional node Devs use typescript but surely that won't solve all your problems. I think your first step might have to be to switch to another ide or configure it better. Because that error should not be happening. NodeJS puts all your code into a function under the hood and then runs that, so there shouldn't be any global variables. The answer would be to have your IDE checked out but idk what you're using. I do however wanna note that I don't understand why you're creating an app in both files. You're not using it in your router file and if you had to, you should find a way of passing it instead. Maybe by exporting a function that takes an app and returns a router.

Answer (score 0):

code on Router.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
```

Use only this line, hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out typescript specifically wants you to use import instead of require, it doesn't recognize "require" the way plain old JS does. Hence the global scope issue.

My fix: use import XYZ from "XYZ" for imports from now on, no requires. Thanks to all below!